# How do I resolve "No administrators were specified" error with the Facebook Like button?

Tags: facebook

I've placed the Facebook Like button iframe code on my [website](http://www.melvilletenniscentre.com.au/).  When I test it, I receive an error:

"name" likes this. · Error.  Clicking on Error gives:

> You failed to provide a valid list of
>   administrators. You need to supply the
>   administrators using either a
>   "fb:app_id" meta tag or a "fb:admins"
>   meta tag to specify a comma-delimited
>   list of Facebook users.

If I view the source of the page, I can see:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="529447119" />
```

What do I need to do to prevent the error?  Do you receive the error

Comment: No, I don't receive the error. How do I unlike it?!

Comment: I've removed the button, and replaced it with AddThis.com code.

Comment: in my blogs fb like box this error appears "You like this. · Admin Page · Insights · Error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen a few questions here about similar things in facebook that are resolved once the url is run through the [Facebook URL Linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) - see if that picks up the admin OpenGraph property.

Next, go to [Facebook Insights](http://facebook.com/insights) and 'claim' your site using the green 'Insights for your website' button at the top left. This will use the OpenGraph property to connect your site with your FB account.

Hope that helps!

Adam

Comment: Hi @adam.  Thanks, that's excellent help.  The linter says: Not CSV. The fb:admins field should be a comma delimited list of Facebook profile IDs (with some whitespace around if you want), i.e. it should match /^\s*[0-9]+(\s*,\s*[0-9]+)*\s*$/. You wrote "steven.doig".  What is wrong with what I entered?

Comment: Ah, it has to be the id *number* - you can't use the name. You can find your number through the 'claim' option I mentioned above (I think yours is 529447119). Also, despite what it says, you can only specify one admin id - it won't accept a comma-separated list.

Answer (score 0):

Two common reasons why this may not work:

- Your facebook username should be included in a meta tag inside of the html header like so:

> ```
> <meta property=”fb:admins” content=”FACEBOOK_USER_ID” />
> ```

Where FACEBOOK_USER_ID is your Facebook username.

- Set your Facebook username by logging into your facebook account. Go to Account > Account Settings > Settings > Username

Comment: I already have that tag in the source code.  I've removed the button, and replaced it with AddThis.com code.